# In compiling error1 and erro2

Tags: compiler-errors, u-boot

Actually i have compiled the u-boot-xilinx and everthing seems to be fine but at the i got the following message.:-

```
 make[1]: *** [demo] Error 1
 make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/Documents/u-boot-xlnx/examples/api'
 make: *** [examples/api] Error 2
```

What is thiS Error 1 and Eroor2 ??
Apart from this the files like u-boot ,u-boot.bin, u-boot.img,u-boot.lds,u-boot.map, u-boot.srec , all are generated.

What are the reason of above errors and are they need to rectified?

Please reply me.

Regards

Aditya

Comment: `make` has detected that a step did not finish successfully, but you're not showing the preceding lines of output which would probably include the error from whatever thing `make` tried to invoke.

Comment: Hi Kusalananda,

Comment: Hi Kusalananda, Actually i want to attach mine files here but i do not how to attach here as there is no option here and when i tried to paste here then no of lines got exceded

Comment: You could at least provide the host environment, toolchain and U-Boot version.  **/home/Documents/** is an unusual directory to build stuff. *"no of lines"* -- Is this an Indian thing? In proper English "no" is not an acceptable substitute for the word "number" (even if the abbreviation was properly punctuated).

Comment: It is a typo mistake. Sorry for that.........